# double wrapping. kashrus in my mouth

Tags: halacha, meat-and-milk

If one has a milchig oven, he can double wrap the food and the food wont become milchig or pass fleish to the oven. If I double wrap a hamburger in a layer of lettuce and a layer of bun, can I have it with milk?

For simplicity's sake, lets pretend the burger I a White Castle "slider" and can be eaten in one gulp.

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=919&st=&pgnum=33&hilite=

Comment: "If I double wrap a hamburger in a layer of lettuce and a layer of bun, can I have it with milk?"  Huh???? The hamburger is meat. How can you have it with milk at the same time even if it's NOT double wrapped?

Comment: @DanF You can't have it at the same time if it's not double wrapped. He's asking about if it is double wrapped

Comment: Do you mean ignoring the minhag of waiting a certain number of hours between meat and milk?

Comment: @Daniel No, he means does that minhag not apply.

Comment: @DoubleAA How do you know that? Are we talking about the case where he swallows the food whole or something like that so it stays double wrapped while in his mouth?

Comment: @Daniel Seemingly.

Comment: @DoubleAA That should really be edited into the question, then.

Comment: @Daniel I have no complaints with edits which serve to better clarify the post.

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm just not certain that's the OP's intent. It would be helpful if the OP could clarify.

Comment: Clint, did you intend this as Purim Torah? White Castle burgers aren't Kosher.

Comment: @loe 1) That's not how to bring a post in line with the policy; you need to remove the other tags and add the footer as well. 2) How do you know that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double wrapping helps for taste transfer via evaporated gases, not direct contact.

Suppose I encapsulated the meat in plastic and swallowed it whole (*please consult with your doctor first*), and would now like to drink some milk: there are two reasons why we wait between meat and milk: in case there is any residue on the teeth, and because some flavor remains in the digestive tract. The former would not apply, but the latter likely would (unless you coated it in something the stomach can't break down at all, in which case you should *really* call you doctor first).

Comment: "some flavor remains in the digestive tract" ESPECIALLY with White Castles(*urp*)! And that distinctive digestive-tract-sourced pickles/ketchup/onions umm...aroma... can last far longer than any waiting period...if you MUST eat something from there, go for the chicken rings or breast sandwiches-your digestive system and nearby friends(any bystanders, actually) will thank you later on.

Answer (score 0):

No.

If the burger is a White Castle slider you cannot have it with milk (or without milk), as [it's not kosher](http://5tjt.com/the-case-of-the-white-castle-hamburger/).

But if this is practically relevant to you, please consult your rabbi, rather than relying on what you read on this site.